# Is there a way to split an Array following a filter

Tags: arrays, filter, swift4.2

I'm finding myself in trouble with an array that has to be divided into two arrays. One only containing prices an the other one only containing descriptions.

For example:

```
var startingArray = ["apple", "30.00", "pizza", "2.00"]
```

And the result should be:

```
var firstArray = ["apple", "pizza"]
var secondArray = ["30.00", "2.00"]
```

Swift 4.2

Is there a way to reach this result? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should want a result like that: `let resultArray = [["name": "apple", "price": "30.00"],  ["name": "pizza", "price": "2.00"]]`, an array of Dictionaries (or event better of custom struct/object). You don't want to have a desynchronization between theses two.

Comment: The fact is that the 'startingArray' is filled up with all the data that a ImageToTextDetector finds in a image and it's always different. Can you make a clearer example?

Comment: And what result is this `ImageToTextDetector` returning, an array of paired elements that belong together like product & price?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want that kind of result.
`apple` is meant to be with `30.00`. `pizza` is meant to be with `2.00`.
If you use these two arrays, if you change the order, remove one, you'll need to do the same operation on the second one.

Instead, use a array of dictionaries:

```
let startingArray = ["apple", "30.00", "pizza", "2.00"]
var final: [[String: String]] = []
for i in stride(from: 0, to: startingArray.count, by: 2) {
   let name = startingArray[i]
    let price = startingArray[i+1]
    final.append(["name": name, "price": price])
}
print("final: \(final)")
```

Output:

```
$> [["name": "apple", "price": "30.00"], ["name": "pizza", "price": "2.00"]]
```

Then, you can do on final array:

```
let first: [String: String] = final[0]
let firstName = first[name]
let firstPrice = first[price]
```

You could also use a tuple, but a better way would be to use a custom struct/class to represent that.

```
struct Grocery {
    let name: String
    let price: Double
    init(name: String, priceStr: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = Double(priceStr) ?? 0
    }
}

let startingArray = ["apple", "30.00", "pizza", "2.00"]
var groceries = [Grocery]()
for i in stride(from: 0, to: startingArray.count, by: 2) {
    let name = startingArray[i]
    let price = startingArray[i+1]
    let grocery = Grocery(name: name, priceStr: price)
    groceries.append(grocery)
}
print("groceries: \(groceries)")
```

Output:

```
$> groceries: [Grocery(name: "apple", price: 30.0), Grocery(name: "pizza", price: 2.0)]
```

Then, you can do on final array:

```
let first: Grocery = groceries[0]
let firstName = first.name
let firstPrice = first.price
```

Note: I used Double for the price, but if you want to keep it as a `String`, it's up to you.

Comment: Using `stride` by `2` would fail if the array has an odd count

Comment: Indeed, I didn't made guard or other safety measures. But if the count is odd, the question is how to interpret it, what value to discard, etc. That's another issue, since I guess the author is ready a Ticket with OCR.

Comment: You could fix it this way `stride(from: 0, to: startingArray.count - startingArray.count % 2, by: 2)`

Comment: You are assuming that the array is like `["apple", "30.00", "pizza"]` or `["apple", "30.00", "2.00"]`, what if it's `["Ticket n°12", "apple", "30.00"]`? Or `["30.00", "apple", "30.00"]`, etc. I think that "your fix" is too narrow. Testing the integrity of the array, is off broad to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
extension Array {
    func separate() -> (odd: [Element], even: [Element]) {
        return self.reduce(into: (odd: [], even: [])) { (acc, element) in
            if (acc.even.count + acc.odd.count) % 2 == 0 {
                acc.odd.append(element)
            } else {
                acc.even.append(element)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let startingArray = ["apple", "30.00", "pizza", "2.00"]

let (firstArray, secondArray) = startingArray.separate()
print(firstArray) // ["apple", "pizza"]
print(secondArray) // ["30.00", "2.00"]
```

---

And using this you can combine array elements into dictionary:

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func dictionaryWithOddEvenRule(uniquingKeysWith combine: (Element, Element) throws -> Element) rethrows -> [Element: Element] {
        let (keys, values) = self.separate()
        let sequence = zip(keys, values)
        return try Dictionary(sequence, uniquingKeysWith: combine)
    }
}
```

or even for general case:

```
extension Array {
    func dictionaryWithOddEvenRule<K, V>(keysTransform: (Element) throws -> K, valueTransform: (Element) throws -> V, uniquingKeysWith combine: (V, V) throws -> V) rethrows -> [K: V] where K: Hashable {
        let (keys, values) = self.separate()
        let sequence = zip(try keys.map(keysTransform), try values.map(valueTransform))
        return try Dictionary.init(sequence, uniquingKeysWith: combine)
    }
}
```

E.g.:

```
enum ExampleError: Error {
    case cantParseDouble
}

do {
    let result: [String: Double] = try startingArray.dictionaryWithOddEvenRule(
        keysTransform: { $0 }, // Transform between array element type to dictionary key type
        valueTransform: {
            // Transform between array element type to dictionary value type
            if let double = Double($0) {
                return double
            } else {
                throw ExampleError.cantParseDouble
            }
        },
        uniquingKeysWith: {
            ($0 + $1)/2 // Handle situation when two identical keys exist 
        }
    )
    print(result) // Handle result
} catch let error {
    print(error) // Handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `forEach` functionality.

After declaring your startingArray, declare two other arrays for Strings and Doubles as:

```
var doubleArray = [String]()
var stringArray = [String]()
```

Then use `forEach` to startingArray to seperate your elements and add accordingly as following:

```
    startingArray.forEach { (element) in
        if let _ = Double(element) {
            doubleArray.append(element)
        } else {
            stringArray.append(element)
        }
    }
```

When you print your arrays, you will see the results as seperated:

```
    print(doubleArray)
    print(stringArray)
```

Comment: Actually he want two separate array of `String` type not `Double` and `String`

Comment: If you don’t care about the result of `map` you might as well use `forEach` instead and skip those `return` statements

Comment: You are right, the result type is not important here, I will edit my answer. Thanks @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 0):

try using

**stride:** *Recommended*

```
let f1 = stride(from: 1, to: startingArray.count, by: 2).map({ startingArray[$0] })
let f2 = stride(from: 0, to: startingArray.count, by: 2).map({ startingArray[$0] })
```

**Filter:**

```
let f1 = startingArray.filter({ Double($0) != nil })
let f2 = startingArray.filter({ !f1.contains($0) })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
var startingArray = ["apple", "30.00", "pizza", "2.00"]

var firstArray: [String] = []
var secondArray: [String] = []

for str in startingArray {
    if let _ = Double(str) {
        firstArray.append(str)
    } else {
        secondArray.append(str)
    }
}

print(firstArray)   //["30.00", "2.00"]
print(secondArray)  //["apple", "pizza"]
```

But as Larme suggests, you're better off be more object-oriented in your approach, and use for example structs:

```
struct Fruit {
    let name: String
    let price: Double
}

var startingArray = ["apple", "30.00", "pizza", "2.00"]

let zipped = zip(startingArray, startingArray.dropFirst())

var fruitArray = [Fruit]()

for couple in zipped {
    let name = couple.0
    if let price = Double(couple.1) {
        let fruit = Fruit(name: name, price: price)
        fruitArray.append(fruit)
    }
}
```